# Average number of pieces of a random piecewise-linear function

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, real-analysis, elementary-proofs, random-functions

Let $I$ be a (nonempty) compact interval in $\mathbb R$ and $a_1,b_1,\ldots,a_L,b_L \in \mathbb R$. Let $\varphi$ be a piecewise function with $T \ge 2$ pieces(for example $T=2$ for the choice $\varphi(t) = \max(0, t)$ for $t\in \mathbb R$). Consider the piecewise-linear function $f:I \rightarrow \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x)=z_L$, where
$$
\begin{split}
z_0&=x,\\
z_l &= \varphi(a_l z_{l-1} + b_l),\;\forall l=1,2,\ldots,L.
\end{split}
$$

Let $a_1,\ldots,a_L$ be drawn i.i.d from some $\mathcal N(0,\sigma_a^2)$ and $b_1,\ldots,b_L$ be drawn i.i.d from some $\mathcal N(0,\sigma_b^2)$.

I'm interested in the distribution of the number of linear pieces of $f$.

## Questions

- What is a good estimate of the average number of linear pieces of $\mathcal f$ as a function of $T$, $L$, $\sigma_a^2$, $\sigma_b^2$, and the length of $I$ ?
- What kinds of techniques can be used for such problems ?

Comment: Doesn't it just depend on the signs of a and b whether the number of linear pieces doubles or not?

Comment: @Dirk Please could be more explicit on your remark  ? :)

Comment: The next $z_l$ is always zero on some intervall. If the next $b$ is negative while $a$ is positive you'll have one more kink. (However, it occurs to me that the number of kinks may even double every layer, so probably I should stop thinking without a piece of paper.)

Comment: @Dirk Thanks for the input. Such arguments can be used to obtain upper bounds on the max number of pieces, but I don't think they can go beyond this to give insight into means, etc. No ?  I have found a result of type Kac-Rice, which from afar at least, should give me something. Indeed, see Theorem 4.1.1 of "Random Fields and their Geometry" https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/cb22/0d3575600c795cb3aabe6e3a19637e86d5e5.pdf. I will write up what I arrive at, asap.